# Install saxon-c on linux

Tags: raspberry-pi, saxon, saxon-c

I don’t understand the installation of saxon/c:

https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation/index.html#!starting/installing/installingLinux

When I unzip `libsaxon-HEC-setup64-v1.2.1.zip` on my raspberry pi and execute the `./libsaxon-HEC-setup64-v1.2.1` I get an error that I can’t execute a binary file:

> Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616787/getting-the-error-bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-erro

Comment: When I do file./libsaxon-HEC-setup64-v1.2.1 I get. Yes I get it. wrong kernel. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I downloaded:
https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/libsaxon-HEC-setup64-v1.2.1.zip

Unzipped and try to run:
./libsaxon-HEC-setup64-v1.2.1

I get error about file not executable:
-bash: ./libsaxon-HEC-setup64-v1.2.1: kan binair bestand Verkeerd uitvoerbaar bestand niet uitvoeren

uname -a
Linux version 5.10.17-v8+ (dom@buildbot) (aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-8 (Ubuntu/Linaro                              8.4.0-3ubuntu1) 8.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #1421 SMP PREEMPT                              Thu May 27 14:01:37 BST 2021

Can someone help?

Comment: Note that for SaxonC 12 there is also an aarch64 linux version https://www.saxonica.com/download/c.xml.